# Get last record for list of ids Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Django model with fields
1.id
2.status
3.name

I have a list of ids [1,5,7]
I want the last record of each id like
model.objects.filter(id__in=list).....

Comment: Why not looking for the id exactly you want instead of the list? I mean `model.objects.filter(id=list_of_ids[-1])`

Comment: Hi Elgin, Thank you for the response. I have a list of ids if I go one by one for each id then will be an expensive method, so in one go I want the latest record of each id in a list. In the table, there are multiple records for one id so I want the latest one for each.

Answer (score -1):

Last record of each id ?! each record has only one unique id.
But if you mean you want the object with the greatest id
I think there are 2 ways to get the last object:

```
queryset = model.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 5, 7]).order_by('id').last()
```

Or you can do this:

```
queryset = model.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 5, 7]).latest('id')
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick response.., I need lastest status of each id, there are many entries for one id, I want latest for each

Comment: Here id is my assetid  please note...@mojixCoder

Answer (score -1):

then `id` field should not be your primary as you can *NOT* have the same primary key in the database, usually this is done as ManyToOne relationship using Foreign keys that you separate the status in a new Model and you even add some fields like occured_on so your Models should be like

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Status(models.Model):
     model_name = Models.ForeignKey(Model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     occured_on = models.DateTime(auto_now_add=True)
  
     class Meta:
         get_latest_by = "id"
```

then you can get the last status by

```
for m in Model.objects.filter().prefetch_related(status_set)
    status = m.status_set.latest.name
```